# Sort tuple list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, visual-studio-2013

Working on C#.NET.
I have this list:

```
List<Tuple<string, float>> sort = new List<Tuple<string, float>>();
```

I want to sort this list by the float value. Eg if the list is like this:

```
a,45
b,2
s,32
se,83.21
te,84
s3,9.5
f,7
```

I want it to be sorted in a descending order, like this:

```
te,84
se,83.21   
a,45
s,32
s3,9.5
f,7
b,2
```

Comment: Whilst I can see that you want it sorted you have not shown how you have already tried to do it.  People are happy to help but this smells like homework and people wont do your work for you.

Comment: You can just use `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to sort the list inplace, you can use the [`Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes `Comparison<T>` argument.

To sort by the `Tuple.Item2` in ascending order, you can use

```
sort.Sort((a, b) => a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2));
```

To sort in descending order, just swap `a` and `b`:

```
sort.Sort((a, b) => b.Item2.CompareTo(a.Item2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't sort the list - you'd create a new list which contains the same items, but is sorted.

```
var sorted = sort.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2).ToList();
```

Comment: Wonder why someone down voted you.  This is what OP asked for.

Comment: Yeah, but it's sad that people are still down voting without comments.  But that's been going on since the beginning of this site.

Comment: I answered this nearly seven years ago. I'm not sure why I said that they "wouldn't sort the list." Obviously you can sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to sort the list:

```
sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.Item2).ToList();
```

Comment: you should use `.OrderByDescending(...)` as OP asked for decending.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new list you can use the [`IComparer<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to create a customer comparer.

```
public class MyCompare : IComparer<Tuple<string, float>>
{
    public int Compare(Tuple<string, float> x, Tuple<string, float> y)
    {
        return y.Item2.CompareTo(x.Item2);
    }
}
```

... then you would use it like this ...

```
sort.Sort(new MyCompare());
```